# Convert HyperV Servers in to HyperV Cluster

Tags: windows-server-2008, hyper-v, high-availability, failovercluster

We have 2 Hyperv Servers and a SAN. When they were configured, High Availability wasn't on the horizon. But it is now.

Can I convert the current servers in place to use Failover Clustering? 
Or 
Would I have to create a cluster with different hardware, migrate the current VMs over to them, and then bring in the older servers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it in place. You'll have to reboot one or more times, so there will be unavailability, but otherwise you can take a running Hyper-V server, add the Cluster Service, Create the AD Cluster and join the Servers without destroying the current configuration.

Side Note: VMs in the Cluster are **not** automatically highly available. You must explicitly "convert" them after the fact. This can be done in Failover Cluster Manager or SCVMM (if you have that).

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do it in place but it's fairly straightforward.  Once once you have the servers in a cluster simply move them in and make them highly available.  Basically:

- Export/backup your VMs
- Add the Failover Clustering feature on both hosts
- Configure networking (probably the biggest pain)
- Carve out storage on your SAN for the clustered shared volume
- Since you only have two hosts you'll also need a little room on your SAN for a Witness Disk
- Start the Failover Cluster Manager and Validate the cluster
- Then "Create a Cluster"
- Move the Vms to the clustered shared volume and make them highly available.

This MS article walks you through it:
http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=12648